# django-pipeline crashes python social auth

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth, django-pipeline

Currently I'm working in a little project that is contemplating social authentication (so python-social-auth is great). Also, I wanna to integrate django-pipeline to handle my assets (css principally).

JS to perform a social sign up:

```
vm.doSocialAuth = function(provider) {
  var authURL = '/auth/login/' + provider + '/?next=/auth/completed/';
  $window.open(authURL, 500, 500);
};
```

Social authentication works fine.

But when I do:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ['pipeline']
PIPELINE = {
    # 'PIPELINE_ENABLED': True,  # Missing this allows pipeline in debug mode
    'STYLESHEETS': {
        'main': {
            'source_filenames': (
              'css/cover.css',
            ),
            'output_filename': 'css/main.css',
            'extra_context': {
                'media': 'screen,projection',
            },
        },
    },
}
```

And I try to make a social sign in, this exception is triggered:

```
ERROR Internal Server Error: /auth/complete/twitter/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dosher/.venvsa/env_hrpro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/dosher/.venvsa/env_hrpro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/dosher/.venvsa/env_hrpro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dosher/.venvsa/env_hrpro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dosher/.venvsa/env_hrpro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/utils.py", line 54, in wrapper
    return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dosher/.venvsa/env_hrpro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/views.py", line 28, in complete
    redirect_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dosher/.venvsa/env_hrpro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/actions.py", line 43, in do_complete
    user = backend.complete(user=user, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dosher/.venvsa/env_hrpro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/base.py", line 41, in complete
    return self.auth_complete(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dosher/.venvsa/env_hrpro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/utils.py", line 229, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dosher/.venvsa/env_hrpro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/oauth.py", line 182, in auth_complete
    return self.do_auth(access_token, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dosher/.venvsa/env_hrpro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/utils.py", line 229, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dosher/.venvsa/env_hrpro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/oauth.py", line 193, in do_auth
    return self.strategy.authenticate(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dosher/.venvsa/env_hrpro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/strategies/django_strategy.py", line 96, in authenticate
    return authenticate(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dosher/.venvsa/env_hrpro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 74, in authenticate
    user = backend.authenticate(**credentials)
  File "/home/dosher/.venvsa/env_hrpro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/base.py", line 82, in authenticate
    return self.pipeline(pipeline, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dosher/.venvsa/env_hrpro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/base.py", line 85, in pipeline
    out = self.run_pipeline(pipeline, pipeline_index, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dosher/.venvsa/env_hrpro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/base.py", line 111, in run_pipeline
    func = module_member(name)
  File "/home/dosher/.venvsa/env_hrpro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/utils.py", line 55, in module_member
    mod, member = name.rsplit('.', 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I don't know if its a issue for python-social-auth library or for django-pipeline, so I've posted it here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I sympathize. I have had so many problems with django-pipeline I don't even know where to start.

Comment: I've just discovered this issue has been discussed in python-social-auth repository, https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/pull/888

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credit for the next answer is all for [Julian Bez](https://github.com/webjunkie), he posted [this](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/pull/888#issuecomment-215690158) comment.

And he is basically suggesting to define a `SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE` variable inside our project's settings file and python-social-auth is going to work smoothly with django-pipeline.

So, here's my `SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE`:

**settings.py**

```
# By defining SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE, we avoid a conflict between django-pipeline
# and python-social-auth.
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',

    # Send a validation email to the user to verify its email address.
    # Disabled by default.
    # 'social.pipeline.mail.mail_validation',

    # Associates the current social details with another user account with
    # a similar email address. Disabled by default.
    # 'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',

    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```